# Prove a quotient group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group with a normal subgroup $M$ such that $G/M$ is abelian. Let $N\geq M$ and $N \unlhd G$. Show $G/N$ is abelian.

**My attempt**:

To show that $G/N$ is abelian, we need to show that for all $x,y \in N,~ xNyN=yNxN$

$G/M$ is abelian, so for any $x,y \in M, xMyM=yMxM$. Since $M$ is a subgroup of $N$, the cosets $xM$ and $yM$ are in $B$. Then, I am stuck, but I feel like I should construct some sort of algebraic manipulation to show $G/N$ is abelian.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with the commutatorsubgroup? In general $G/M$ is abelian iff $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ that contains the commutatorsubgroup. If $M$ does that, then so does $N$.

Comment: Thanks, this is some thing I proved a couple weeks ago, and I just learned correspondence thm, which I am not that familiar with. @drhab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By correspondence theorem $N/M$ is normal in $G/M$.

By third isomorphism theorem $$G/N \cong \frac{G/M}{N/M} $$But $G/M$ is abelian, and a quotient of an abelian group is abelian, so $G/N$ is abelian.

Comment: I don't really understand why this gets upvotes (and also the answer of @Timbuc) while the answer purely on basics lacks upvotes. Don't understand me wrong. The answers are okay and diversity in answers is a good thing. But the problem can allready be solved by someone who has no familiarity yet with all this (correspondence, isomorphism theorem, commutatorsubgroup). The OP might be in that stage.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why N/M is normal? I am not that familiar with the correspondence theorem.

Comment: @Calico: $N/M$ is normal in $G/M$ because $N$ is normal in $G$; this is simply contained in the statement of correspondence theorem

Comment: @Calico: If you study group theory correspondence theorem is very important

Answer (score 4):

Note that $xNyN:=xyN$ and $xMyM:=xyM$. The fact that $N$ and $M$ are normal implies that these multiplications are well defined.

It is to be shown that for each pair $x,y\in G$ we have $xyN=yxN$ or equivalently $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in N$.
This is a direct consequence of $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in M\subseteq N$ (equivalent with $xyM=yxM$).

---

The commutatorsubgroup of $G$, often denoted as $[G,G]$, is the subgroup that is generated by elements of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. It is a characteristic, hence normal subgroup and is somehow decisive when it comes to the question whether a quotient $G/K$ is abelian:

$$G/K\text{ is abelian }\iff [G,G]\subseteq K$$

Comment: I think $\;G\;$ is even fully invariant, not only characteristic.

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras It is not about $G$ but about $[G,G]$. Btw, what is fully invariant?

Comment: I meant to write $\;G'\;$ but somehow failed. Anyway, also $\;G\;$ is fully invariant, indeed. As for the derived group: for any endomorphism $\;\phi:G\to G\;,\;\;[\phi x\,,\,\phi y]=\phi[x,y]\implies \phi G'\le G'\;$

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras So endo's correspond with it (like auto's to it with characteristic) if I understand you well. Thank you. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 3):

$$G/M\;\;\text{abelian}\;\iff\;G'=[G:G]\le M$$

But

$$M\le N\implies\;\text{also}\;\;G'\le N\implies G/N\;\;\text{abelian}$$